# Laravel Testing Registration redirection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

**Laravel 5.4.31**

I am using the auth scaffolding by running `php artisan make:auth` and `php artisan migrate`.

I overridden the register function as follows in my `RegisterController`.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect('/login')->with('message', Config::get('constants.registration.success'));
}
```

I am writing a test as follows.

```
public function a_user_is_redirected_to_login_page_with_message_after_registration() {

    $user = factory( 'App\User' )->raw();

    $response = $this->post( '/register', $user );

    $response = $this->followRedirects($response);

    $response
        ->assertSee( Config::get( 'constants.registration.success' ) );
}
```

I have defined the `followRedirects` function in the parent `TestCase` class and I have my configuration `constants.registration.success` setup correctly.

But I am getting the following assertion error.

```
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 5.14 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\UsersTest::a_user_is_redirected_to_login_page_with_message_after_registration
Failed asserting that '<!DOCTYPE html>
the whole html content goes here
</html>
' contains "You have been registered. But your account has to be activated by the administrator before you can login. Please contact the administrator.".

C:\Users\Acer\Documents\codehub\laravel\dashbox\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:197
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\codehub\laravel\dashbox\tests\Feature\UsersTest.php:43
```

The message session variable is also not showing on my browser. What could be wrong?

**Update**
My observation is that: after successful registration on the `POST /register` route, for some reason unknown to me it first redirects to `/` and then to `login` during testing. And it seems to work fine when I remove the `$this->validator($request->all())->validate();` call from `register` function in `RegisterController`.

Comment: Can you post the PHPUnit assertion error in your question

Comment: @Ken I have updated the question with the test error.

Comment: Does the HTML that you get back expected output... is it just missing the text or is it a "whoops" page. If it is the "whoops" page go to you Handler.php (exceptions) and in the `render` method just `throw $exception; ` as the first line rerun the test and you should see your exception + stacktrace

Comment: try to modify this line `$response = $this->post( '/register', $user );` to `$response = $this->post( '/register', $user )->assertRedirect('/login');`

Comment: @AmrAly I have tried that and it fails with error `Failed to assert that the two strings are equal: Actual and Expected: -'http://localhost/login' +'http://localhost'`. I have also updated the question to explain my observation.

Comment: It occurs to me that your middlewares could causing the problem try to use `WithoutMiddleware` trait in your test class.